# Are there methods to connect to private Git server over SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-server

I have at my disposal a server where i downloaded GIT.

#### Aim:

use it a remote repository and connect from a local computer to make **push** and **pop** operations.

I saw that online is necessary to use **ssh** protocol.

The issue is that the service where the server is, doesn't let me to use this protocol.

#### Question:

Is there any other way to connect from a local computer to a remote server in order to use **GIT** ?

I have a **windows server**
**P.S:** I cannot use **GitHub** since is required that the source codes have to be avaible just on our own server.

Comment: Honestly, I'd get another provider. There's no reason the repository has to live on a Windows server, and I have trouble imaging a Linux provider that would disallow SSH.

Comment: If its Windows-Server, just spin up a hypervised Linux machine :D

Answer (score 0):

The two standard ways of connecting to a Git server are SSH and HTTP.  The Git documentation indicates how to set up the Apache web server in the `git-http-backend` documentation, and it should be theoretically possible to configure other web servers as well, although documentation is provided only for Apache and Lighttpd.

If you don't want to set up Apache or another HTTP server, then you'll need to use SSH.  Do note that most of the documentation for Git servers focuses on Unix systems because it's very uncommon to host a standalone Git server (that is, one without additional hosting software) on Windows.  It should be possible, but you'll likely find more resources and support if you use Linux.